# Error after insert HTML code in DOM in console (Chrome browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get HTML in line: `room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();` and insert after load `step-02.php` in `.thisRoom` but this error is in Console.

```
$(function () {
var hotel = [];
var lenHotel = 0;
$('#forPrice').on('click', function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() > 0 && $(this).val() < 10) {
            var room = {};
            room["room"] = $(this).attr('room');
            room["price"] = $(this).attr('price');
            room["val"] = $(this).val();
            room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();

            hotel.push(room);
        }
    });
    lenHotel = Object.keys(hotel).length;
    console.log(hotel);
});

$('#forPrice').click(function () {
    $('#Step-01').hide();
    $('#Step-02').show();
    $('.hiddenAndShow').hide();
    $( "#Step-02" ).load( 'step_02', function () {
        for(var i = 0; i <= lenHotel; i++) {
            $("#Step-02").find('.thisRoom').append("<tr class=\"selectRowRoom\">");
            $("#Step-02").find('.thisRoom').append(hotel[i]['html']);
            $("#Step-02").find('.thisRoom').append("</tr>")
        }
    });
});
})
```

And error in console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
```

Comment: What are you doing here, are you trying to get the HTML's parents html? In that case, that doesn't work, since HTML is the super parent and does not have any parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= lenHotel; i++)
```

Should be this

```
for(var i = 0; i < lenHotel; i++)
```

Your accessing an element in the array that doesnt exist.